# How do I use aggregation operators in a $match in MongoDB (for example $year or $dayOfMonth)?

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have a collection full of documents with a created_date attribute.  I'd like to send these documents through an aggregation pipeline to do some work on them.  Ideally I would like to filter them using a $match before I do any other work on them so that I can take advantage of indexes however I can't figure out how to use the new $year/$month/$dayOfMonth operators in my $match expression.

There are a few examples floating around of how to use the operators in a $project operation but I'm concerned that by placing a $project as the first step in my pipeline then I've lost access to my indexes (MongoDB documentation indicates that the first expression must be a $match to take advantage of indexes).

Sample data:

```
{
    post_body: 'This is the body of test post 1',
    created_date: ISODate('2012-09-29T05:23:41Z')
    comments: 48
}
{
    post_body: 'This is the body of test post 2',
    created_date: ISODate('2012-09-24T12:34:13Z')
    comments: 10
}
{
    post_body: 'This is the body of test post 3',
    created_date: ISODate('2012-08-16T12:34:13Z')
    comments: 10
}
```

I'd like to run this through an aggregation pipeline to  get the total comments on all posts made in September

```
{
    aggregate: 'posts',
    pipeline: [
         {$match:
             /*Can I use the $year/$month operators here to match Sept 2012?
             $year:created_date : 2012,
             $month:created_date : 9
             */
             /*or does this have to be 
             created_date : 
                  {$gte:{$date:'2012-09-01T04:00:00Z'}, 
                  $lt: {$date:'2012-10-01T04:00:00Z'} }
             */
         },
         {$group:
             {_id: '0',
              totalComments:{$sum:'$comments'}
             }
          }
    ]
 }
```

This works but the match loses access to any indexes for more complicated queries:

```
{
    aggregate: 'posts',
    pipeline: [
         {$project:
              {
                   month : {$month:'$created_date'},
                   year : {$year:'$created_date'}
              }
         },
         {$match:
              {
                   month:9,
                   year: 2012
               }
         },
         {$group:
             {_id: '0',
              totalComments:{$sum:'$comments'}
             }
          }
    ]
 }
```

Comment: what type of value do you want to match?  can you give an example with actual date values?

Comment: Can you post some sample data and sample output?

Comment: Have added some sample data and an example of what I'm trying to do

Comment: Are those strings or dates? You won't be able to perform date queries on them if they're strings.

Comment: They are dates.  My question is on the syntax of using the $year/$month/$dayOfMonth operators in a $match clause

Comment: Do you need to group by month and year for some reason? If so, I would $project AFTER the $match, but using the $match as per my original code sample. You can always $match again on month and year. Otherwise, you're not indexing month and year, just date. One alternative, is to store the date in two formats. Why not store a duplicate month and year field that you can index directly if that's the way you need to query? I'm still not clear on why you want to filter on month and date fields at all though. The date query you already have works pretty well to find posts in September.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

As you already found, you cannot $match on fields that are not in the document (it works exactly the same way that find works) and if you use $project first then you will lose the ability to use indexes.

What you can do instead is combine your efforts as follows:

```
{
    aggregate: 'posts',
    pipeline: [
         {$match: {
             created_date : 
                  {$gte:{$date:'2012-09-01T04:00:00Z'}, 
                  $lt:  {date:'2012-10-01T04:00:00Z'} 
                  }}
             }
         },
         {$group:
             {_id: '0',
              totalComments:{$sum:'$comments'}
             }
          }
    ]
 }
```

The above only gives you aggregation for September, if you wanted to aggregate for multiple months, you can for example:

```
{
    aggregate: 'posts',
    pipeline: [
         {$match: {
             created_date : 
                  { $gte:'2012-07-01T04:00:00Z', 
                    $lt: '2012-10-01T04:00:00Z'
                  }
         },
         {$project: {
              comments: 1,
              new_created: {
                        "yr" : {"$year" : "$created_date"},
                        "mo" : {"$month" : "$created_date"}
                     }
              }
         },
         {$group:
             {_id: "$new_created",
              totalComments:{$sum:'$comments'}
             }
          }
    ]
 }
```

and you'll get back something like:

```
{
    "result" : [
        {
            "_id" : {
                "yr" : 2012,
                "mo" : 7
            },
            "totalComments" : 5
        },
        {
            "_id" : {
                "yr" : 2012,
                "mo" : 8
            },
            "totalComments" : 19
        },
        {
            "_id" : {
                "yr" : 2012,
                "mo" : 9
            },
            "totalComments" : 21
        }
    ],
    "ok" : 1
}
```

Comment: Exactly! He didn't say so in the question, but that's the only reason I can imagine you'd need month and year in the pipeline.

Comment: "you cannot $match on fields that are not in the document"    that answers my question, thanks

Comment: Actually, you can if they're in the pipeline, like year and month are. What you can't do is use an index on them, since there won't be one.

Comment: @cirrus it's semantics at that point :)  once you $project them, they _are_ in the document so you can $match them in the next step, but of course, you are right - the benefit of index is gone by then...  I also agree with your proposal to store month (and year) separately if it's going to help a lot to do this sort of aggregation.

Comment: The dates should be wrapped in ISODate(..) or?

Answer (score 4):

Let's look at building some pipelines that involve operations that are already familiar to us. So, we're going to look at the following stages:

- `match` - this is filtering stage, similar to `find`.
- `project`
- `sort`
- `skip`
- `limit`

We might ask ourself why these stages are necessary, given that this functionality is already provided in the `MongoDB` query language, and the reason is because we need these stages to support the more complex analytics-oriented functionality that's included with the aggregation framework. The below query is simply equal to a `find`:

```
db.companies.aggregate([{
  $match: {
    founded_year: 2004
  }
}, ])
```

Let's introduce a project stage in this aggregation pipeline:

```
db.companies.aggregate([{
  $match: {
    founded_year: 2004
  }
}, {
  $project: {
    _id: 0,
    name: 1,
    founded_year: 1
  }
}])
```

We use `aggregate` method for implementing aggregation framework. The aggregation pipelines are merely an array of documents. Each of the document should stipulate a particular stage operator. So, in the above case we've an aggregation pipeline with **two** stages. The `$match` stage is passing the documents one at a time to `$project` stage.

Let's extend to `limit` stage:

```
db.companies.aggregate([{
  $match: {
    founded_year: 2004
  }
}, {
  $limit: 5
}, {
  $project: {
    _id: 0,
    name: 1
  }
}])
```

This gets the **matching** documents and limits to **five** before projecting out the fields. So, projection is working only on **5** documents. Assume, if we were to do something like this:

```
db.companies.aggregate([{
  $match: {
    founded_year: 2004
  }
}, {
  $project: {
    _id: 0,
    name: 1
  }
}, {
  $limit: 5
}])
```

This gets the **matching** documents and projects those large number of documents and finally limits to **five**. So, projection is working on large number of documents and finally limiting to **5**. This gives us a lesson that we should **limit the documents to those which are absolutely necessary** to be passed to the next stage. Now, let's look at `sort` stage:

```
db.companies.aggregate([{
  $match: {
    founded_year: 2004
  }
}, {
  $sort: {
    name: 1
  }
}, {
  $limit: 5
}, {
  $project: {
    _id: 0,
    name: 1
  }
}])
```

This will sort all documents by name and give only **5** out of them. Assume, if we were to do something like this:

```
db.companies.aggregate([{
  $match: {
    founded_year: 2004
  }
}, {
  $limit: 5
}, {
  $sort: {
    name: 1
  }
}, {
  $project: {
    _id: 0,
    name: 1
  }
}])
```

This will take first **5** documents and sort them. Let's add the `skip` stage:

```
db.companies.aggregate([{
  $match: {
    founded_year: 2004
  }
}, {
  $sort: {
    name: 1
  }
}, {
  $skip: 10
}, {
  $limit: 5
}, {
  $project: {
    _id: 0,
    name: 1
  }
}, ])
```

This will sort **all** the documents and skip the initial **10** documents and return to us. We should try to include `$match` stages as early as possible in the pipeline. To filter documents using a `$match` stage, we use the same syntax for constructing query documents (filters) as we do for `find()`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this;

```
db.createCollection("so");
db.so.remove();
db.so.insert([
{
    post_body: 'This is the body of test post 1',
    created_date: ISODate('2012-09-29T05:23:41Z'),
    comments: 48
},
{
    post_body: 'This is the body of test post 2',
    created_date: ISODate('2012-09-24T12:34:13Z'),
    comments: 10
},
{
    post_body: 'This is the body of test post 3',
    created_date: ISODate('2012-08-16T12:34:13Z'),
    comments: 10
}
]);
//db.so.find();

db.so.ensureIndex({"created_date":1});
db.runCommand({
    aggregate:"so",
    pipeline:[
        {
            $match: { // filter only those posts in september
                created_date: { $gte: ISODate('2012-09-01'), $lt: ISODate('2012-10-01') }
            }
        },
        {
            $group: {
                _id: null, // no shared key
                comments: { $sum: "$comments" } // total comments for all the posts in the pipeline
            }
        },
]
//,explain:true
});
```

Result is;

```
{ "result" : [ { "_id" : null, "comments" : 58 } ], "ok" : 1 }
```

So you could also modify your previous example to do this, although I'm not sure why you'd want to, unless you plan on doing something else with month and year in the pipeline;

```
{
    aggregate: 'posts',
    pipeline: [
     {$match: { created_date: { $gte: ISODate('2012-09-01'), $lt: ISODate('2012-10-01') } } },
     {$project:
          {
               month : {$month:'$created_date'},
               year : {$year:'$created_date'}
          }
     },
     {$match:
          {
               month:9,
               year: 2012
           }
     },
     {$group:
         {_id: '0',
          totalComments:{$sum:'$comments'}
         }
      }
    ]
 }
```

Comment: I'm running this through the Java runCommand which is why I'm using $date instead of ISODate.  But using the $gte and $lt operators is exactly what I posted in my original post if you look at my example.  I'm asking about an alternative.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't look at your second code sample before I posted. I thought you were concerned about the order of the $match statement. What's your concern over the match statement as it stands? It will use an index on created_date. Moreover, I'm not sure what you're trying to achieve with $project, but if you put that before a match, then it won't be healthy.