# MongoDB change $and from aggregate query to implicit and

Tags: python, mongodb, datetime, aggregation-framework, pymongo

In the below query I'm trying to get all the records added in certain month and year by matching given month and year in timestamp but not iso.

```
{
   "$match":{
      "expr":{
         "$and":[
            {
               "$eq":[
                  {
                     "$year":"$timestamp"
                  },
                  2016
               ]
            },
            {
               "$eq":[
                  {
                     "$month":"$timestamp"
                  },
                  1
               ]
            }
         ]
      }
   }
}
```

but above line throws "pymongo.errors.OperationFailure: unknown operator: $and" error in python script.

How do i change the $and in my aggregate query to implicit AND, so that my python script runs without error.

**P.S :**

The query works fine in mongo 3.6. The error is because of the missing $ in expr, my apologies.

Comment: Please add a sample documents from your collection

Comment: Please look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12694490/how-do-i-use-aggregation-operators-in-a-match-in-mongodb-for-example-year-or

Comment: Is the missing $ in expr just a typo ? Are you using the latest compatible 3.6 python driver ? If yes, I'm not sure why this is not supported and you have 2 options. First option to replace your match stage with `$project/$addFields` and `$match` in two stages and second option is to use `$redact` stage

Comment: First option is already provided in linked question. Second option you can use `{ "$redact":{ "cond":{ "$and":[ { "$eq":[ { "$year":"$timestamp" }, 2016 ] }, { "$eq":[ { "$month":"$timestamp" }, 1 ] } ] }, "$$KEEP", "$$PRUNE" } }`

Comment: @Veeram yes i have 3.6 python driver the error was because of missing $ in expr, my apologies. 
But when i pass "variable" instead of 2016 in the above example  inside $eq  it fails it this expected ?

Comment: No it is not. Can i see your code ?

Comment: @Veeram  here is my piece of code:

yr ='2016'
month = '01'
    
"pipeline":[\
        {"$match": {"$expr":{"$and":[{"$eq":[{"$year":"$timestamp"}, yr]}, {"$eq":[{"$month":"$timestamp"}, month]}]}}},

Comment: it is numbers right ?  `yr =2016 &  month = 1`